# Excel VBA: Trouble pasting formats from table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a few tables in different worksheets that I want to compile in another sheet, however I’m having trouble getting the formatting to paste across. 
My current code is:

```
Sub Compiler()

Dim wbRaw As Workbook
Set wbRaw = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsCompiled As Worksheet
Set wsCompiled = wbRaw.Sheets("ALL PROGRAMMES COMPILED")
Dim wsACF As Worksheet
Set wsACF = wbRaw.Sheets("ACF")
Dim wsASPIRE As Worksheet
Set wsASPIRE = wbRaw.Sheets("ASPIRE")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wsCompiled.Cells.ClearContents

wsACF.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy

With wsCompiled
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False


wsASPIRE.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Copy

With wsCompiled
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The first table pastes across fine with the correct formatting, but the next table only pastes the values, with no formatting.

If I remove the offset from the copy line:

```
wsASPIRE.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy
```

The formatting pastes fine, but this then includes the headers from the second table which messes up the compiled data.

Can anyone explain why this happens and any suggestions how I can get around this?

Comment: i can't reproduce the error...

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed to find out *why* the formatting of tables does not paste across, however I figured out a workaround to the problem by looping through the tables in each worksheet and then unlisting them.:

```
Sub LoopTables()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
                 tbl.Unlist
        Next tbl
    Next ws

End Sub
```